# How to provide bank list in OpenBankProject

Tags: open-banking

I set up local OpenBankProject OBP-API from https://github.com/OpenBankProject/OBP-API. When i hit the endpoint http://localhost:8080/obp/v3.0.0/banks i get the answer like

```
{"banks":[]}
```

So the banks list is empty. I haven't found the solution how to add any bank to the list, tried via props files but it seems it should be done in other way. The question is: how can I fill this list of banks?

Answer (score 2):

You can add banks by using this endpoint: https://psd2-apiexplorer.openbankproject.com/?psd2=true?ignoredefcat=true&tags=#OBPv2_2_0-createBank i.e. /obp/v2.2.0/banks

Note: You must have the CanCreateBank role for this to work.